# httpOnly Cookies vs Authorization headers for passing JWT

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt

so I'm kind of confused about the correct way to pass JWT authorization, I know a common approach is that you can use a Authorization header to verify it, something like this:

```js
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.token;
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(403).json("Token is not valid!");
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json("You're not authenticated");
  }
};
```

However, if I used cookie to store my JWT token after I login such as:

```js
res.cookie("accessToken", accessToken, { httpOnly: true });
res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, { httpOnly: true });
```

Does that mean I can ignore the authHeader above and use directly from the cookie to verify my Token? Something like:

```js
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  //USING TOKEN FROM COOKIES
  const accessToken = req.cookies.accessToken;
  const refreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken;
  if (accessToken && refreshToken) {
    jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.JWT_KEY, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(403).json("Token is not valid!");
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json("You're not authenticated");
  }
};
```

Thanks for any clarification

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bad practice to store the tokens as cookies directly, as anyone accessing the computer can access them. The cookies are not protected when they are stored in the browser.

Just setting **HttpOnly** is also a bad practice, you should also set the **Secure** and **SameSite** attribute on the cookies as well to make them more secure. Even better encrypting them before you store them inside the cookie.

A better approach can be to look at the **BFF** pattern as described [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf)

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Hi, how about if I store the accessToken in memory so client can set it as authorization header, and store the refreshToken in httpOnly cookie so although my accessToken is exposed, it’s short-lived, is it a better approach? Cause i can’t find any implementation for the BFF pattern in code, thanks

Comment: The problem is that if you are using a standard OpenID Connect/OAuth authorization provider, then you need to call it using the refresh token in a API request, so your JavaScript still needs to have access to both tokens. If you still want to use tokens in the browser, consider using a library like https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS